# E-mail signature does not work properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I designed an e-mail signature to my client, first I tried it with tables via photoshop but some problems occured -gaps between td's- etc. And I tried all the solutions that stackoverflow community provides but I cannot solve.

After that I tried to make it with some basic html/css coding and it works ok with desktop and mail applications on desktops...

But in mobile divs are broken because of the sizes I think. I need this code "responsive".

Is there any easy solution regarding to this code? Sorry for my bad English.

Thank you!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
 p {
 font-family: "Open Sans Light";
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #434343;
 padding:0;
 margin:0em;
}

</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<div style="width:540px; height:230px; background-color:white; display:block;">

  <div style="width:38px; height:230px; background-color:white; float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/nzLxWQZW/leftline.jpg"></img>
  </div>
  
  <div style="width:305px; height:230px; background-color:white; float:left; display:block;">
    <div style="width:305px; height:86px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#434343;"><p style="font-weight:bold; margin-top:24px; font-size:18px; padding:0; margin-bottom:0;">DAVID MYERS</p><p style="margin:0; padding:0;">Marketing Manager</p>
    </div>
        <div style="width:305px; height:27px; background-color:white; float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/WzFvNLd6/dot.jpg"></img>
    </div>
        <div style="width:305px; height:64px; background-color:white; float:left; display:block;">
          <p style="margin:0; padding:0;">P: +972.54.563.1729</p>
          <p style="margin:0; padding:0;">M: +972.54.563.1729</p>
    </div>
        <div style="width:305px; height:53px; background-color:#f6f6f6; float:left; display:block;">
        <p style="margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:0; margin-right:0; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold;">www.stayviagem.com</p>
          <p style="padding:0; margin:0; font-size:10px;">85 Broad Street, Suite 28-088, New York, NY 10004</p>
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
  <div style="width:197px; height:230px; background-color:white; float:left; display:block;">
    <div style="width:197px; height:178px; background-color:white;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/6pLN5hpS/logo-viagem.jpg"></img></div>
        <div style="width:197px; height:52px; background-color:#461d7b;  float:left; display:block;">
        
         <a href="https://www.facebook.com/stayviagem" target="_blank"><div style="width:48px; height:52px; background-color:#200;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/8PvSxGQT/facebook.jpg"></img></div></a>
         <a href="https://www.instagram.com/stayviagem" target="_blank"><div style="width:34px; height:52px; background-color:#200;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/jSrbb1tP/instagram.jpg"></img></div></a>
         <a href="https://www.twitter.com/stayviagem" target="_blank"><div style="width:32px; height:52px; background-color:#200;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/9XK2xMkx/twitter.jpg"></img></div></a>
         <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/stayviagem/" target="_blank"><div style="width:34px; height:52px; background-color:#200;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/26XYN8SS/pinterest.jpg"></img></div></a>
         <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWJBkDUX-YwAggoM9zHVmWQ" target="_blank"><div style="width:48px; height:52px; background-color:#200;  float:left; display:block;"><img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gjCPrSR9/youtube.jpg"></img></div></a>
        
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will never get something remotely complex to work properly in e-mail.  Every e-mail client is different, and has different restrictions.  Use tables and hope it works well enough.  Otherwise, do something simpler.

Comment: Hi @Brad, thank you for your reply, it seems a little bit complex but it works well in all clients that I need to be sure. I just have "mobile" problem. It's about sizes and I'm new at coding html/css... I need to solve this issue for now :(

Comment: Firstly, you should show us a screenshot for what it looks on mobile.  Second, you should try the table layout I suggested.  Third... you may not actually be able to solve this problem directly.  Getting HTML in e-mail to work is a nightmare... lots of hacks and quirks you have to work around.  Also, try a tool like Litmus to test it.  https://litmus.com/

Comment: I believe that there's an issue like "max-width" or that media query @Brad but I cannot figure it out. I don't have any other problem with the code.

Comment: -1 for still not providing a screenshot of what you're seeing so we know specifically what your issue is, and not bothering to even try the suggestions made to you.

Comment: @Brad, you got me wrong... Possibly it's because of my English. I did not try to be rude or something else... But there's one thing I cannot understand about your answers; I want to understand how to make my 540px width design decrease into 280px (for example) depending on any device... I'm a newbie on html/css and want to learn that maybe basic stuff... Using "max-width" instead of "width" etc... Site did not allow me to upload images because I'm a new user. Hope that's not a problem using links to show images... Here's my screenshot https://postimg.cc/QFNgLKQ6

Comment: And @Brad. this problem occurs the same when I look to my html file with mobile browser... Not just with e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Email is way too simple to implement complex HTML and CSS code. You'll be trying for years.

Unfortunately, even if it does appear to be working on multiple devices, there are so many email clients, domains and devices out there that there will be a combination that doesn't support HTML - or, as you've encountered, a device that isn't responding well to HTML.

In my personal opinion, I would try to avoid using HTML to implement a signature, because it will be very very tricky to do. Email was never designed to be able to present HTML, but it can easily work with formatting and images. Which leads me to my solution...

If you're trying to display business details to the recipient, why can't you design a really good looking image in Photoshop and attach it to the bottom of every email? Almost all companies use this method of displaying a good-looking email signature because there aren't very many more methods of doing it otherwise. Even if you do want to make it responsive, it needs to adapt to various screen sizes, abilities to present HTML and CSS, as well as different online and desktop clients. I think you might be trying to achieve something a little tricky.

Comment: Hi @Aaron thank you for your reply!

The problem is that, the client wants some of the contents as text... So I need to do it like this... And I'm curious about one thing... I'm testing this one with every possible mail client I would work with and everything is ok. 

Let's don't think it's an e-mail signature. I need to make this code responsive to a mobile phone. Need some info like "use max-width" or "you need to set this to that" :)

Comment: I need to set the container div's max-width and height (and so inside divs...) responsively decrease depending on device... Don't want to change anything like float etc... Same design with smaller size that fits to the screen.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure HTML is going to be able to query that sort of information in an email.. And with mobile devices that can be rotated, how it will dynamically change...

Comment: let's think it's not an e-mail signature

Comment: @ErenAlkan It doesn't matter at all what your client wants.  It's your job to *interpret* what your client thinks they want, and get the best possible solution.  It also doesn't matter at all what *you think* is the solution, if that solution clearly doesn't work.  Aaron has provided you with direct advice, as have I.  There are realities that you must accept if you are to figure out a workable solution.  You can't get what you want by rejecting the reality in front of you.  "Let's think it's not an e-mail signature" is such a ridiculous comment... your whole problem is that this is e-mail.

Comment: @ErenAlkan Okay, so if we think it's not an email signature - it's possible. But as soon as you "think" it's an email signature again, it's not possible. Just "thinking" something doesn't change reality. I'm sorry I can't provide a solution.